# How to make a circle with different arc with CSS or SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Just like this:

[image]

It has different width.

Comment: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you do this in SVG is to place one circle directly on top of the other.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="70" fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="5"
          stroke-dasharray="413.4 440" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"/>
  
</svg>
```

The two additional attributes on the second (front) circle perform the following functions:

`stroke-dasharray="413.4 440"` makes a dash pattern with the effect of drawing 94% of the circle circumference (2 * PI * 70 = 440).

`transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"` rotates the circle 90 degrees anti-clockwise so that the "progress bar" starts at 12 o'clock. By default the dash pattern of a circle starts at 3 o'clock.